# Error when trying to run a simple program in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new to node js when i try to execute the below program am getting an exception as

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'Gemini*123',
    database : 'test'
});

connection.connect();

var queryString = "select * user_details";

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log('Post Titles: ', rows[i].user_name);
    }
});

connection.end();
```

**"Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user_details' at line 1"?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your query String should be `var querystring = "SELECT * FROM user_details"` and not `SELECT * user_details`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put 'From' on your query:

```
var queryString = "select * from user_details";
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, your SQL is wrong - you missed out the `FROM` keyword from your FROM clause.

Your for loop also might result in an error

`for (var i in rows)` will iterate over all the properties of the object.  You probably just want to iterate over the entries of the array, so you'll want to iterate over just the indices instead

```
for (var idx = 0; idx < rows.length; idx++) {
  var row = rows[idx];
  ...
}
```

or you can go functional:

```
rows.forEach(function (row) {
  ...
}
```